# VBA to Transfer different fields in excel into one word document without a table

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I have an excel spreadsheet where i work out my quotation data. I have been then copying and pasting the different totals for each line of the quote into a Word document. I am trying to get tht code right to transfer each individual field into different parts of the word doc with one click instead of manually copying each one. There are 10 to 20 lines with $amounts that i want to transfer to my word template

In Excel I have

```
    Qty           50
    Components    40
    Hardware      130
    Panel         375
    NRE           850
```

Then in Word I have

```
    Qty           
    PCB Cost
    Components    
    Hardware      
    Panel         
    NRE          
    USD Exchange
    Total
```

How can i get the numbers from excel into the correct lines in word?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: How is the data in excel formatted? How is the data in Word formatted? In other words is it all on one row in excel? is it all in one column in Word? Some more information would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to set bookmarks in the word document at the locations where you want to data to appear. So to transfer the quantity place a bookmark called "quantity" just to the right of the text "Qty". You can then use Bookmarks("quantity") to refer to that location. You haven't said whether you want to run your code in Word and fetch the excel data, or run it in Excel and push it to Word - but the principle is the same. Set a reference in the code running app to the other, declare a variable to point to the other app, launch it, open the source or receiving file, declare the source range as an excel range object (lets say we call it rSource) and declare a word range object (lets call it myqty) to point to Bookmarks("quantity").range
you can then say
myqty = rSource.text

Answer (score 0):

If it's always the same workbook & range of cells, you can link the document or its template to the workbook so there is nothing to copy/paste each time. To set up such a link, copy a given Excel range, then paste it into your document or template using Paste Special, with the 'paste link' option and your preferred paste format. That way the document - or a new document created from the template - will automatically reflect the Excel data. If you're using a template, you might then break the links (e.g. via Ctrl-A, Ctrl-Shift-F9) so the new documents don't keep updating when you re-open them.